# CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS Macro enabled?

Tags: usb

I am trying to install a USB device on my Fedora 21 machine. The manual for the USB device mentions that it does not support kernels which are configured to automatically assign minor numbers to USB devices, and that the CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS should not be set, but I am unable to tell if this is set for my Fedora machine. What is default setting for Fedora out of the box? Any way to tell using a command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked on my system:

```
[root@localhost boot]$ cat config-3.18.9-200.fc21.x86_64 | grep CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS

# CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS is not set
```

Does the '#' the CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MACROS is commented out, but still not set. I'm not 100% sure.